# Python 3.3 for() loop iteration processing time growing exponentially?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I have a simple Python (3.3) application in which the processing time between iterations gets longer over each iteration. I believe I've isolated the problem to the `bytes()` function, as you will see below. The code looks like it would be constant, n-time complexity. However, when run it actually shoots up to about n^2-time. I am providing two blocks of code. The first block is the offending block, which feels something like n^2-time complexity. The second block is a small refactor that removes `bytes()` from handling the input. Here's the first block:

```
import hashlib
def gethash(data):
  return hashlib.sha1(data).hexdigest()
body = b"blob 5\01234"

for i in range(1, 100000):
  hashout = gethash(body+bytes(i))
  if(i%1000==0):
    print(".")
```

(Linux `time` utility output for this block): real 0m12.742s - user 0m12.188s - sys 0m0.536s

And here's the second block, refactored to exclude the use of `bytes()` and which has a constant processing time between iterations (n-time complexity, as seems correct):

```
import hashlib
def gethash(data):
  return hashlib.sha1(data.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
body = "blob 5\01234"

for i in range(1, 100000):
  hashout = gethash(body+str(i))
  if(i%1000==0):
    print(".")
```

(Linux `time` utility output for this block): real 0m0.305s - user 0m0.296s - sys 0m0.008s

I am using Linux Mint 16 (kernel 3.11.0-12-generic on x86_64) with Python 3.3.2. I have simplified this code greatly to be more expressive of the central issue. I primarily use Python 3 and can write somewhat non-trivial applications in Python, but I cannot claim to have a Pythonic mindset. Being mindful of this, I've tried to run both of these code blocks in Python 2.7.5, and they both iterate "normally" for a constant amount of time (n-time complexity). I don't know enough about that version and its functions to know if this is meaningful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bytes(i)` creates an `i`-length `bytes` object full of zeros. See the [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytearray) documentation; constructor arguments for `bytes` are interpreted the same way.

To fix this, encode a string:

```
  hashout = gethash(body+str(i).encode('utf-8'))
```

I've picked UTF-8 because you did, but the proper encoding may depend on the context you want to use it in.

Comment: So then `bytes(3)` doesn't do what I think it does, which would be converting integer `3` into its byte-representation? It initializes a zeroed 3-length list. As you can see in my original question, I already had solved the "problem" in the source, but what then should I use to return a byte-representation of an integer without initializing a huge list?

Comment: @L0j1k: By "byte-representation", do you mean `b"3"` or `b"\x03"`? If you want the first thing, the code is in the answer.